# Facebook like and share buttons causes everything underneath to dissapear until fully load

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-share

I'm new here as I didn't post anything but SO sure helped me a lot.
So, in this website http://www.myworld-24.com/Acasa/ keeping FB's like and share buttons in the header caused the rest of the page underneath them to disappear until fully loaded.
I've moved them in the footer and used css to position them into the header but I don't think that's a great solution.
I've made a simpler example here http://www.myworld-24.com/test.html
What is to be done?
PS: sorry for bad english

Comment: Have you tried moving the code that embeds the JS SDK to the end of your body element?

Comment: Yes I did but nothing changed. I tried to load it with $(window).load() also and it wasn't a solution.

Comment: Can you clarify the "disappears" part? I just checked your `test.html` and it loads fine, without any elements disappearing

Comment: Nice! It seems that FB updated SDK. That example has two squares. The red one was the one that wasn't displayed until the FB buttons completed to load. I didn't checked until now because I've removed the SDK from the website and only left it on the test page. Ok, problem solved.